# Failed to instantiate module - Angular UI Form Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting errors when I am setting up Angular UI form with a new application.

Here's the code;

*Index.html*

```
<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/vendor.js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-form-validation/dist/angular-ui-form-validation.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

*Bower.Json*

```
{
  "name": "easijob",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
  "modernizr": "2.8.x",
  "angular": "1.2.24",
  "angular-resource": "1.2.x",
  "angular-ui-router": "0.2.x",
  "jquery": "2.1.1",
  "angular-ui-form-validation": "~1.1.15"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.24",
    "jquery": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

*app.js*

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('easijob', ['directives.customvalidation.customValidationsTypes',
                       'ngResource',
                       'ui.router',
                       'ENV'])
   // Routing for the app.
   .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
     $stateProvider
     .state('app', {
     abstract: true,
       views: {
         'header': {
           templateUrl: 'partials/layout/sections/header.html',
           controller: function($scope, $state) {
             $scope.$state = $state;
           }
         },
         'footer': {
           templateUrl: 'partials/layout/sections/footer.html'
         }
      }
    })
    ;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signup/candidate');
  })
  // On State Change, redefine layout type class based on route.
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $rootScope.layoutVariant = toState.layoutType || 'one-column';
  });
})
;
```

[image]

Any ideas?

B

Comment: Where is this module define directives.customvalidation.customValidationsTypes

Comment: That module is defined in angular-ui-form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 'directives.customvalidation.customValidationTypes' not ''directives.customvalidation.customValidation**s**Types'.

[here](https://github.com/nelsonomuto/angular-ui-form-validation/blob/master/app/scripts/directives/customvalidationtypes/customValidationTypes.js)

So:

```
angular.module('easijob', ['directives.customvalidation.customValidationTypes',
                       'ngResource',
                       'ui.router',
                       'ENV'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, eventually got there yesterday. Added an issue which has now been fixed. The documentation stated the **s**, and I copied and pasted.